# Execution order of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the chain of promises below. By looking at the logger statements, I would expect the console to show:

> '2. Getting room', '3. Getting spontaneous session', '3A. Getting
>   spontaneous session', '4. Attaching to meeting', '4A. Attached to
>   meeting',

But instead I am getting:

> '2. Getting room', '3. Getting spontaneous session', '3A. Getting
>   spontaneous session', '4A. Attached to meeting', '4. Attaching to
>   meeting',

Can someone explain why the third 'then' is being hit before anything is returned from the second 'then'?

```
logger.log('2. Getting room', 2, room);
RoomStore.getRoom(room, function(err, sessionIds) {
    let user = req.body.user;

    logger.log('2A. Getting room', 2, room);
    logger.log('3. Getting spontaneous session', 2, room);
    getSpontaneousZipdxSession(user, room).
    then(function(urls) {
        resolvedUrls = urls;
        logger.log('3A. Getting spontaneous session', 2, room);
        return connectTokboxZip(urls.url, sessionIds[0], room);
    }).
    then(function() {
        if (req.body.translated === 'true') {
            connectTokboxZip(resolvedUrls.englishSessionUrl, sessionIds[1], room).then(function() {
                logger.log('4. Attaching to meeting', 2, room);
                return attachToMeeting(user, room);
            });
        }
        else {
            logger.log('4. Attaching to meeting', 2, room);
            return attachToMeeting(user, room);
        }
    }).
    then(function() {
        logger.log('4A. Attached to meeting', 2, room);
        logger.log('Connecting room to zipdx SUCCESS!', 2, room);
        communications.sendZipDxConnectedMessage(room);
        resp.sendStatus(200);
    }).
    catch(function(error) {
        logger.log('Connecting room to zipdx failed: ' + error, 2, room);
        resp.statusMessage = error;
        resp.status(500).end();
    });
});
```

Comment: When asking for help, particularly with something like this, please take the time to format and indent the code consistently and readably. I've fixed it for you on this occasion.

Comment: Um...you're not seeing "2A" at any point?

Comment: Thank you, I had real trouble pasting it in and formatting it this time for some reason. Sorry, yes I am seeing 2A. It's 4 and 4A which come in an unexpected order.

Comment: You forgot to put a `return` in front of `connectTokboxZip(...`.

Comment: I don't expect 4A before 4. I expect 4, then 4A. But the console is showing 4A is hit first

Comment: You have a nested `.then` inside a `.then`, so the nested one executes last of all, and it returns `'4. Attaching to meeting'`.

Comment: @Si-N: Ah, okay. I misread.

Comment: Maybe something to consider : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning the promise returned by:

```
connectTokboxZip()
```

This makes the containing `then()` return undefined instead of a promise. It should look like:

```
then(function() {
    if (req.body.translated === 'true') {
       return  connectTokboxZip(resolvedUrls.englishSessionUrl, sessionIds[1], room).then(function() {
            logger.log('4. Attaching to meeting', 2, room);
            return attachToMeeting(user, room);
        });
    }
    else {
        logger.log('4. Attaching to meeting', 2, room);
        return attachToMeeting(user, room);
    }
}).
```