# Order of script execution with Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I know that this question is almost the same as this one: [Execution order of Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547900/execution-order-of-promises) but can someone explain to me where is my mistake?
I have the next functions:

```
// The main function
function startTesting() {
    console.info("--- Thanks! Testing is running... ---");
    checkFolderExistence(dirPath)
        .then(checkFolderContent)
        .then(searchForImportFolder)
        .then(connectToDB)
        .catch(err => console.error("*** ERROR *** " + err));
}

function checkFolderExistence(path) {
    console.info('--- Checking the folder "' + path + '" existence... ---');
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir(path, (err) => {
            if(err) {
                console.error('*** ERROR **** The folder "C:\\For_testing" doesn\'t exist. Testing is stopped!!! ***');
            } else {
                console.info("--- The folder \"C:\\For_testing\" exists... ---");
                resolve(path);
            };
        });
    });
    return promise;
}

function checkFolderContent(path) {
    console.info('--- Checking the folder "' + path + '" content... ---');
    filesArray = fs.readdirSync(path);
    if(filesArray.length == 0) {
        console.error('*** ERROR *** There are no any files in ' + path + '. Testing is stopped!!! ***');
    } else {
        console.info('--- The folder is checked. It contains the next files: ---');
        for(let i = 0; i < filesArray.length; i++) {
            console.info(filesArray[i]);
        }
    };
}

function searchForImportFolder() {
    console.info('--- Searching for ".../Import" folder... ---');
    fs.readdir(destFolderPath64, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            fs.readdir(destFolderPath32, (err) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.error('*** ERROR *** The folder ".../Import" was not found ***');
                } else {
                    console.info('--- The folder ".../Import" was successfully found... ---');
                    trueDestPath = destFolderPath32;
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.info('--- The folder "C:/Program Files (x86)/StoreLine/Office/Import" was successfully found... ---');
            trueDestPath = destFolderPath64;
        }
    });
}

function connectToDB() {
    console.info('--- Connecting to the database... ---');
    let pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    pool.connect()
        .then(pool => {
            console.info("--- Connected to the database! ---");
            readDB(pool)
                .then(function() {
                    console.info("--- All needed information from DB was successfully received ---");
            })
                 .catch(err => console.error("*** ERROR *** " + err));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(configWithoutPassw);
            pool.connect()
                .then(pool => {
                    console.info("--- Connected to the database without the password! ---");
                    readDB(pool)
                        .then(function() {
                            console.info("--- All needed information from the DB was successfully received ---");
                        })
                        .catch(err => console.error("*** ERROR ***" + err));
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error("*** ERROR *** Can't connect to the DB ***")
                    sql.close();
                });
        });
}
```

I need a strict order of execution of the functions: `checkFolderContent` => `searchForImportFolder` => `connectToDB`.

In fact the execution is the next: `checkFolderContent` is executed fully, then `searchForImportFolder` starts execute (I can see the line "--- Searching for ".../Import" folder... ---" in a console) but right after that `connectToDB` starts and the next line "--- Connecting to the database... ---" is appeared. And after that line I see "--- The folder ".../Import" was successfully found... ---" from the previous function.

What did I do wrong? I've read that in `.then()` function should return a promise. How can I do that?

Comment: use async await to maintain order of script execution

Comment: Your `searchForImportFolder` is asynchronous, but does not return a promise. Thus, the next `then` is executed immediately with the return value of `searchForImportFolder`, which is `undefined` because nothing was returned; `trueDestPath` is set some time in the future, ignored and sad.

Comment: @MohamedAshiff - `async`/`await` won't help here until the fundamental issue with `searchForImportFolder` is fixed.

Comment: You can also [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining) your promises.

Comment: @lependu - The OP **is** chaining his promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchForImportFolder` doesn't return a promise, so the chain doesn't wait for that promise to complete. Do the same thing in `searchForImportFolder` that you've done in `checkFolderExistence`: Wrap the callback-style API in a promise.

A couple of notes:

- `checkFolderExistence` should call `reject` in the error path; it doesn't currently.
- Node provides a [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function you can use to wrap callback-style API calls in promises, rather than doing it manually. Or you could use the [`promisify-fs` `npm` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-fs), or the [`promisify` `npm` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify) that lets you promisify an entire API at once, or Node's own [experimental promises API for `fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).
- You might want to make `checkFolderContent` async (again using promises) rather than using `readdirSync`, which holds up the main thread waiting on I/O.
- If you're using any recent version of Node, you might want to switch to using `async` functions and the `await` keyword, as it lets you write your logical flow rather than writing a bunch of callbacks.
- `searchForImportFolder` should *return* its result rather than setting a global.

So for instance, here are `checkFolderExistence` and `searchForImportFolder` using `util.promisify` (these assume `searchForImportFolder` should *return* its result, so you'll have to adjust code using it):

```
const { promisify } = require("util");

const readdirPromise = promisify(fs.readdir);

function checkFolderExistence(path) {
    console.info('--- Checking the folder "' + path + '" existence... ---');
    return readdirPromise(path)
        .then(path => {
            console.info("--- The folder \"C:\\For_testing\" exists... ---");
            return path;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('*** ERROR **** The folder "C:\\For_testing" doesn\'t exist. Testing is stopped!!! ***');
        });
}

// ...

function searchForImportFolder() {
    console.info('--- Searching for ".../Import" folder... ---');
    return readdirPromise(destFolderPath64)
        .then(() => {
            console.info('--- The folder "C:/Program Files (x86)/StoreLine/Office/Import" was successfully found... ---');
            return destFolderPath64;
        })
        .catch(() => readdirPromise(destFolderPath32))
        .then(() => {
            console.info('--- The folder ".../Import" was successfully found... ---');
            return destFolderPath32;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('*** ERROR *** The folder ".../Import" was not found ***');
            throw error;
        });
}
```

If you don't need all that logging, `checkFolderExistence` just becomes `readdirPromise`, and `searchForImportFolder` becomes:

Or if you don't need all that logging (presumably that was for debugging):

```
const { promisify } = require("util");

const readdirPromise = promisify(fs.readdir);

// ...

function searchForImportFolder() {
    console.info('--- Searching for ".../Import" folder... ---');
    return readdirPromise(destFolderPath64)
        .then(() => {
            return destFolderPath64;
        })
        .catch(() => readdirPromise(destFolderPath32));
}
```

And here they are using `util.promisify` and `async`/`await`:

Or using `util.promisify` and `async`/`await`:

```
const { promisify } = require("util");

const readdirPromise = promisify(fs.readdir);

// ...

async function searchForImportFolder() {
    try {
        await readdirPromise(destFolderPath64);
        return destFolderPath64;
    } catch (error) {
        await readdirPromise(destFolderPath32);
        return destFolderPath32;
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid searching for the two different folders repeatedly, a simple tactic is just to remember the promise from `searchForImportFolder` and then use `then` on it any time you need that value:

```
const importFolderPromise = searchForImportFolder();
```

...then when you need it:

```
importFolderPromise.then(folder => {/*...*/});
```

...or in an `async` function:

```
const folder = await importFolderPromise;
```

The search will only happen once.

Comment: There's also [`promisify-fs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-fs) that already has promises out of the box, as a replacement for `fs`.

Comment: @Amadan - Good link. There's also Node's own [promises API for `fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api), but it's still experimental.